# custom validation with multiple row, multiple columns in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Model `"Table1"` and we would have around 8 fields like `f1..f8`. I need to validate such that the value in the `f1 of the row1` is not present in the `f1 to f8 of the other rows` and similarly for all the fields.

To be more clear, the value in one column should not be present in the other columns of the other row but the value can be same in the same row.

How can I build such validation?

Comment: How will you know that which field should have which row? And how will you recognize row?

Comment: @user123 Sorry, if I was not clear. Actually, what I try is similar to uniqueness validation where the field value should not be repeated. But the difference is, I need to compare the value not only with the corresponding field but with all the 8 fields that I have. For example: field1 contains val1 and val1 should not be present in another rows either in the field1 or in other fields but the val1 can be repeated in the same row i.e field2..field8 of same row. Hope this would have explained better. Please don't hesitate to ask again, even if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom validation like this

```
validate f1_unique?

def f1_unique?
    if Table1.where("f1=:f1_val OR f2=:f1_val OR ... f8=:f1_val", f1_val: f1).exists?
        errors.add(:f1, "is duplicate")
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following validation.

```
validate :uniq_field_validation

def uniq_field_validation
  field_names = [:f1, :f2, :f3]
  field_names.each do |field_name|
    _other_rows = self.class.all - [self]
    field_values = []
    field_names.each { |field| field_values << _other_rows.map { |row| row[field] } }

    errors.add(field_name.to_sym, "is present in other fields") if field_values.include?(self[field_name])
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, if was not clear but this does validation within the same row. I need it to be validated with other rows and in fact the same row can contain the same values in different fields. Actually this is similar to uniqueness validation of field but I need to compare with all the 8 fields of the other rows. Hope this would have explained more clearly.

Comment: I tried this one and that didn't work too. The previous one didn't allow me to enter the same value within same row but now it allows. But still this does not check for the value in other fields of other rows.

Answer (score -1):

```
validates :attr, uniqueness: {scope: [:attr1, ... , :attrn]}
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Sorry, this won't work. And I really look for something else which you may be not clear from my question.